# Is there a way to keep the BGM going while paused?

Tags: the-witcher

I started playing *The Witcher Enhanced Edition* from Steam and during the tutorial sequence it was suggested to me to pause the game if I wanted to change my attack style, when I did it though the background music fades out.

to me this sorta ruins the feel the music creates (especially for a boss battle) so I am wondering if there is a way to keep the BGM going while I'm paused?

Comment: There is a better way to change fighting styles without pausing the game. Just use the keys Z,X,C. If I remember correctly each one represents a different fighting stance, let me know if it works

Comment: The other way to change style (that I find quicker because of where my fingers already are) is to keep pressing the key for the sword you have out to cycle the fighting styles e.g. if you have steel sword out and are in strong stance, press Q once to go to fast or press it twice to go to group.